# fenced_divs pandoc extension in RMarkdown

Tags: yaml, rstudio, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

Is there a way, either in YAML or within an R script/Rmd, to turn on the `fenced_divs` pandoc extension?

If possible, I would prefer being able to turn on `fenced_divs` without having to specify it inside each individual output format in the YAML block but rather once, globally.

The reason is that I want to have within-document links to items that are not headers using the same code for .docx and .html.

Thanks.

Comment: [How can we pass pandoc_args to yaml header in rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290659/how-can-we-pass-pandoc-args-to-yaml-header-in-rmarkdown) does give a generic way to do this _inside_ each output format (which is annoying, why not permit global defaults overridden within formats but whatever). The bigger problem turned out that I was using a pre fenced-divs version of Pandoc.

Comment: The fact that the [RStudio devs](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2283) are talking about syntax highlighting for `fenced_divs` implies that in newer versions of the stack this is supported. I guess it's time to think about updating my OS.

Comment: One last comment for posterity: the following all also give various versions of "not as simple as you think": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395374/what-can-i-control-with-yaml-header-options-in-pandoc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492145/how-can-i-specify-pandocs-markdown-extensions-using-a-yaml-block
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43629039/can-i-specify-command-line-options-in-a-pandoc-markdown-document
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483240/can-i-set-command-line-arguments-using-the-yaml-metadata